# Error: input of anonymous composite types is not implemented

Tags: postgresql, where-clause, in-clause

Why am I getting this error since I am trying to run the below?

```
WITH rakes AS (
   SELECT 
      SUM(tbl.rake) AS rake, usr.site_id 
   FROM 
      table1 as tbl 
   INNER JOIN 
      user as usr 
   ON 
      usr.id= tbl.user_id 
   WHERE 
      usr.origin <> 'test' 
   AND 
      tbl.created_at>= '2021-01-01' 
   AND 
       tbl.created_at< '2021-07-25' GROUP BY usr.site_id ), 
fees AS ( 
   SELECT 
      SUM(fees) AS fees, site_id 
   FROM 
      table1 
   WHERE 
      csv_date>= '2021-01-01' 
   AND 
      csv_date< '2021-07-25' GROUP BY site_id 
) 
SELECT (COALESCE(r.rake,0) + COALESCE(f.fees,0))::numeric(18,2) AS calc
FROM rakes AS r JOIN
     fees AS f
       ON r.site_id=f.site_id
WHERE COALESCE(r.site_id, f.site_id) IN ('domain.gr', 'domain.uk','domain.com')
```

Comment: Can you show the `CREATE TABLE` statements for `rakes` and `fees`?

Comment: WITH rakes AS (SELECT SUM(tbl.rake) AS rake, usr.site_id
FROM table1 as tbl
INNER JOIN user as usr ON usr.id= tbl.user_id
WHERE usr.origin <> 'test'
AND tbl.created_at>= '2021-01-01'
AND tbl.created_at< '2021-07-25'
GROUP BY usr.site_id
),
fees AS ( SELECT  SUM(fees) AS fees, site_id
FROM table1
WHERE  csv_date>= '2021-01-01' AND csv_date< '2021-07-25'
GROUP BY site_id
)

Comment: Still, I don't know the column types.

Comment: Are you sure that's the query generating the error? The error sounds as if you had some useless parentheses around more than one column (`select (a,b)` instead of `select a,b`)  but your current code doesn't contain something like that.

Comment: First, can you provide the information @LaurenzAlbe requested on the table schema? Second, in what client are you running this query?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.